# Mistakenly edited something while booting Windows. Now it doesn't boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, bootloader

I have a Dell Inspiron 6400 dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.10.. 
I had just finished a session on Win7 which was extremely slow, and I decided to restart in safe mode to uninstall some unnecessary software.

I went past grub, and booted into windows and was tapping the F12 key furiously to get the Safe mode option. I mistakenly pressed F11 repeatedly, I saw something getting edited , like a boot line or something and I pressed Escape hoping it would cancel out whatever I typed. I booted into Windows itself (not safe mode) , did the uninstalling, and performed a restart.

EDIT : I pressed F11 repeatedly and got this. This is what is the edited version looks like (incl. approx screen layout)

```
  EDIT BOOT OPTIONS
  EDIT BOOT OPTIONS FOR : WINDOWS 7

  PATH : \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINLOAD.EXE

  PARTITION : 1

  HARD DISK : 5b210d4e

  [ /NOEXECUTE=OPTIN

  ]
```

The last line, that is OPTIN can only be edited . I'm sure I edited this. Any idea what the default is ?

Now my Windows doesn't boot. When I select Windows from the grub menu, a screen comes giving me two options - Launch system recovery and boot Windows Normally.
I chose boot normally, but as soon as the animates Win7 logo appears, there is a flash of BSOD and it restarts. I tried the 'Launch System Recovery' option but it doesn't seem to find any Operating System to locate any System Recovery Points.

Comment: Renew Grub from Ubuntu by executing `sudo update-grub` in a terminal, this will undo possible changes in Grub. If that doesn't help, I'd say you've installed something he's missing now.

Comment: doesn't sound like a grub problem; sounds like you've confused the win7 bootloader (which grub is chainloading).  don't think update-grub will help here.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking . I went past the grub alright.  I'll try getting that Boot Editor screen again and post what exactly I edited.

Comment: Have you tried the repair option from the Install CD?

Comment: Problem with the repair option (no need for CD though on Windows 7) is that it'll probably overwrite the boot loader and erase grub. Be careful where you tread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use msconfig or bcdedit to modify the win7/vista boot config
I presume that changes in msconfig should overwrite any errors for you.

http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-use-bcdedit-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

On another PC, download the Windows 10 media creation tool and use it to make a win 10 installer on USB
change boot order so USB is first, hdd second
boot from installer
on screen after languages, choose repair this pc, not install.
choose troubleshoot
choose reset this PC
might need to wipe it all as I don't know what settings it would have if you deleted registry
After choice, PC will restart and reinstall win 10

If reset doesn't work, do a fresh install using the USB
follow this guide: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-windows-10-clean-install.html